# Validating copy of large amount data

Tags: mysql, database, plsql, oracle11g

I have written an algorithm which basically copies large amount of data from Oracle database to mysql database. Copying is done by column date. It takes about one day to copy items which I need. It copies about 5 000 000 items.

The question is, is there a possibility to check if the data copied to mysql database is valid and is exactly the same. Checking only the count of items does not solve this problem, because there was noticed some items with null value instead of some values presented in oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a third program, where you can access both dbs and compare them, or you set up a gateway between oracle amd mysql for comparing all or selected tables and rows.
[MySQL- Oracle Enterprise Gateway Integration Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/documentation/mysql-integration-guide-428960.pdf)

Comment: The thing is i forgot to mention it. That the data i am making copy of is dinamic and can change after and during copying. So if i would try to write simple check to chech record to record it would not help. Making a dump copy is not a solution, after initial copying there is synchronyse and other things are done to ensure that we have fresh data.

Comment: What ever you do, you have to choose a certain point in time. During that time there should be no changes. If you can not guarantee that, you can just test certain parts you think as comparable. But with the gateway you should also be able to copy the data. If I understand your description, you copy by columndate. If this and the content does not change independendly, you can compare all rows with the same column date.